# Outside a datatemplate On..PropertyValueChanged doesn't run

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a custom control which uses On(propertyname)ValueChanged to read items from a dictionary and set up the parameters for that control.

I would also like to use that control as a stand alone and not just a databound control.

So how come OnPropertyValueChanged only works in a dataset?

Do Dependency properties only work from the xaml, does that mean i will have to bind from properties in the container class? (may have answered my own question)

in my mainpage.xaml

```
    <local:spriteToggleButton x:Name="testButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding testString, ElementName=mainPage}" Correct="true" Margin="93,561,93,63" Grid.Row="1" Sprites="{Binding testSprites, ElementName=mainPage}" />
```

in mainpage.xaml.cs

```
    testSprites.Add("idle", idlesprite); // a dictionary of a custom sprite object
    testSprites.Add("highlighted", highlightedsprite);
    testSprites.Add("selected", selectedsprite);

    testString = "this is a test"; // this property is picked up by the binding.
```

when i add sprites from the binding it runs the dependency property changed callback but the properties inside the spriteToggleButton class are not updating when the control is used standalone

this is my dependency property changed callback

```
    private static void OnSpritesPropertyValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as spriteToggleButton;
        var sprites = e.NewValue as Dictionary<string, Quiz.Sprite>;

        control.idleSprite = sprites["idle"];
        control.selectedSprite = sprites["selected"];
        control.highlightedSprite = sprites["highlighted"];
    }
```

this is inside my spriteToggleButton

```
 <local:spriteView x:Name="Idle" Width="294" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Sprite="{Binding idleSprite, ElementName=toggleSpriteControl}"  />
 ...
```

Sprite is also a dependency property in that control

Comment: A little sample code would help here.

Comment: The OnSpritesPropertyChanged will only fire when the Sprites property itself is changed, not when the collection contents change.  Could you give the exact code that is not working and your expected outcome?

Comment: it actually fires when I use this parameter `Sprites="{Binding testSprites, ElementName=mainPage}"` to get the property from the mainpage class. what it doesn't do is update those controls in the control.

Comment: @Joseph:  Can you also show the code that doesn't work?  Its not clear to me what you think "Standalone" means?  It appears you mean that you are using the control without data binding.  Thats fine but how then do you assign the `Sprites` property when used "standalone" and what code do you have in your `get` and `set` property accessors for the `Sprites` property?

Comment: @Joseph: Please don't post code or xaml in a comment, its unreadable, just edit your question again with additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much suspect that you haven't implemented `idleSprite`, `selectedSprite` and `highlightedSprite` of the `spriteToggleButton` class as dependency properties.  Do that and it should start working.

For what its worth it appears you are implementing `spriteToggleButton` using a `UserControl`, I would instead derive from `ToggleButton` and replace the default template.